# Fail to start uiautomator2 by Appium on Android 3rd emulator when running a full pipeline on Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins-pipeline, appium, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

In my pipeline script, I use this command to start my Android UI automation on a 3rd party emulator.

`".\\gradlew cucumber -Pargs=\"-rerun ${rerun_times} -enable-report ${enable_report} -timezone GMT+08:00 -suite ${running_scope}\" -b android\\build.gradle && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"`

this command would invoke couple Gradle tasks:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPDRe.png)

and my full pipeline has several stages, looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PyRb.png)

I put the above command in the last stage - Initiate AT, I don't see anything in the 4 stages before would affect AT running
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR9oM.png)

**My issue is**:
When I run the full script on pipeline project 1, I can see Appium Settings apk flashing on the screen (that often means Appium server started), then nothing happened, here's the log
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1xuj.png)

I tried to separate the command and run it alone in pipeline project 2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR9oM.png)

I can see my debug app running successfully after Appium Settings apk flashing, here's the log I expected
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1jPd.png)

Can somebody help, I only start to use Jenkins pipeline this month, and I'm really confused.

Answer (score 0):

I broke up each stage in the script and reassembled them with the Gradle command, finally I proved my point of 5 stages having nothing to do with each other, And I found the origin of the issue.
What caused my problem was an environment variable I set up in environment block, HTTP_PROXY, I didn't know it also is what Appium will be using when it invokes uiautomator2, I still don't know, it's just my guess.

Comment: Can you share your script example? Or at least the basic structure of it?